# In C, I'm using Boolean logic to go to the beginning of my program via a while loop, but my variables are not reinitializing after I tell them to

Tags: c, while-loop, initialization, boolean-logic

I'm trying to make a program that allows a user to discover the sum of the even terms in the Fibonacci series up to an arbitrary, user-defined length. I'm making it so that the user has a chance to make new calculations if they choose. I'm using boolean logic and a while loop to achieve a sort of program restart.

The program executes fine the first time. However, on each subsequent user-input, the previous answer affects the current one. I tried to reinitialize my variables to their initial values (i = 1, j = 2, k = 0, and sum = 0) at the beginning of the while loop, but it's still not giving me the desired result. Thanks for the help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    bool stayAlive = true; 
    long int sum = 0; //The sum of all even Fibonacci numbers
    long int i = 1; //initial 1st value of the Fibonacci sequence
    long int j = 2; //initial 2nd value of the Fibonacci sequence
    long int k = 0; //initial 3rd value of the Fibonacci sequence
    int x = 0;
    char name[50];
    printf("Hello, may I have your name?\n\n");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    putchar('\n');
    while(stayAlive)
    {
        printf("Hello %s! This program will sum up all of the evenly valued terms from\nthe Fibonacci sequence, up until an upper limit term specified by the user.\n",name);
        printf("Set this limit: "); 
        scanf("%d",&x); 
        putchar('\n');
        char c;
        while(k < x)//WHILE the "last term" is LESS than the "max term"
        {   
                        i ==1;
                        j ==2;
                        k ==0;
                        sum ==0;
            k = i + j;
            if(k%2==0)
                sum +=k;
            i = j;
            j = k;
        }

        printf("The sum of all of the evenly valued terms of the Fibonacci sequence up until\nthe value %d is %d.",x,sum); puts("\n");
        printf("Try another calculation? (Y/N) ");
        scanf("%s", &c);
        if(c == 'y'|| c == 'Y')
            continue;
        else
            printf("\nThanks for using this program, %s!",name);//This name character is not outputting here, even though it outputs earlier
            getchar();
            break;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `k == 0`? There is your problem.

Comment: I'd suggest you use functions...

Comment: @squiguy, I modified k==0 to k=0 and then omitting it altogether, it's still not giving me the right answer the second time around.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &c);` == undefined behaviour! What is `sizeof "Y"`? What is `sizeof (c)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to:

> **reinitialize** my variables to their initial values (i = 1, j = 2, k =
>   0, and sum = 0) at the beginning of the while loop

put :

```
sum = 0; 
i = 1; 
j = 2; 
k = 0;
```

**inside** the while loop.

Also remove these lines:

```
i ==1;
j ==2;
k ==0;
sum ==0;
```

Plus, you can use %c instead:

`scanf("%c", &c);`

Since you are reading only one character.

Comment: I tried doing this. Essentially what you are saying, is replace i ==1 with i = 1, and j =1 etc. right?

Comment: Yes, you can do that too. You can reinitialize the variables after you scan the new input as well. You may also reinitialize the variables inside `if(c == 'y'|| c == 'Y')` like @user1914292 said. Just make sure that you put those reinitializations inside the while loop (before you perform Fibonacci series operations though).

Comment: Initializing after works, but not at the beginning of the while loop for some odd reason. I have one more question if you don't mind answering. You alluded to scanf("%c", &c); For some reason, my "name" variable wasn't rendered the last time around until I implemented the change that you suggested. However, on the flip side of that implementation, it prevents the user from having the option of typing 'Y' or 'N.' sending it to the last line "Thank you for using the program [name]" Any insight on how to fix this?

Comment: I don't really get the question but I think it's caused by _stdin is buffered_. You can fix it by adding 1 space before %c like this : `scanf(" %c", &c);`.    

Alternatively to the above solution, you can add `fflush(stdin);` before `scanf("%c", &c);`. By doing `fflush`, the content within input buffer will be clear (aka flush) before the program starts reading new input from scanf.

Comment: And yes, you can ask as many questions as you want to :) I'm here to help and please do tell me if the solution above doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: As well as, you need `{ }` for `else`. Curly braces are **required** for multiple lines. However, I recommend you to put curly braces as much as possible, even if there's one line. Simply adding curly braces increase readability and you can avoid possible errors when you need to add something in that particular block of code.

Comment: Perhaps you haven't read the manual... `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't initialize the values the second time around.

After the following code:

```
if(c == 'y'|| c == 'Y')
        continue;
```

You're still in the while(stayAlive) loop.

So you should initialize your sum etc. After the if(c == 'y'|| c == 'Y') statement

Comment: I edited this code, did you mean something like this? I can't get this particular code to run due to syntax reasons.

Answer (score 1):

How do you absorb information from this website? By reading... If you have to ask us for help for *this*, then your current method of reading obviously isn't working. Which book are you reading?

I think your program should look something like this, and others may agree:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char name[50];
    int c;

    puts("Hello, may I have your name?");
    assert(scanf("%49s", &name) == 1);

    do {
        unsigned int upper_limit = 0, x = 1, y = 2, sum = 0;

        printf("Hello %s! This program will sum up all of the evenly valued terms "
               "the Fibonacci sequence, up until an upper limit term specified by "
               "the user.\n", name);
        puts("Set this limit:"); 
        assert(scanf("%u",&upper_limit) == 1);

        while (x < upper_limit) {
            if (x % 2 == 0) { sum += x; }
            x += y;

            if (y >= upper_limit) { break; }
            if (y % 2 == 0) { sum += y; }
            y += x;
        }

        printf("The sum of all of the evenly valued terms of the Fibonacci "
               "sequence up until the value %u is %u.\n", upper_limit, sum);
        puts("Try another calculation? (Y/N)");
        c = getchar();
    } while (c == 'Y' || c == 'y');

    printf("Thanks for using this program, %s!\n", name); //This name character IS outputting here, because '\n' goes at the end ;)
    getchar();
}
```

You'll notice that many variables are located more locally to their use. This is because they don't *need* to be declared outside of that loop; Those variables are only used within that loop, so that's where they should be declared. How would you convert my loop into a `for` loop? Hint: `for (int c = 'Y'; c == 'Y' || c == 'y'; c = /* TODO */)`

You'll also notice use of the `assert` macro. It might pay to do some research, find out what this macro is meant to be used for and replace it with something more suitable, to ensure that input is correctly read and converted by scanf. *Don't just ignore the return value*, and **certainly don't put side-effects into an assertion like I did in this example**.

In one place I used `getchar` where you used `scanf`. This is because:

1. The `scanf` return value was ignored, where the failure mechanism in this case *isn't* ignored. Perhaps it'd be a good idea for you to write your own standard compliant [`fscanf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/scanf.html), from scratch, so that you can understand what the return values represent and why they're *not* meant to be ignored.
2. The pointer provided to `scanf` was not suitable to store a string that contains "Y" or "y"; That `char` can only store one byte, where `sizeof "Y"` and `sizeof "y"` indicates that these two strings need *two* bytes. Perhaps it'd be a good idea to write your own standard compliant [`strlen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strlen.html), from scratch, so that you can understand why the *second byte* is needed.

Alternatively, consider *reading the manuals, carefully*.

Comment: `assert(scanf("%49s", &name) == 1);` --> 1) Line of code is only in _debug_ mode. 20  `&name` is not the right type.  If wanting to stay with `asert()`, Use `if (scanf("%49s", name) != 1) assert(0);`

Comment: @chux I do wish you'd have read the entire answer, specifically the bold part. If it isn't clear enough from that, what makes you think it'll be clear from your comment all the way down here? I'm not changing the code; there comes a point where we stop babying programmers, and they need to think about fixing the erroneous code that they copy/paste from the internet. Alternatively, we could duplicate warnings all over the internet. ‍♂️

Answer (score -1):

When you need to start again your program you can call main() function.

Example:

`if (condition)
{ main();)}`